# how to make get request from one google spreadsheet to another google spreadshee?

Tags: google-apps-script

i want to sent get request by using script on google spreadsheet. Trigger of this requset is edit by spreadsheet by user. The idea was next:user change data in spreadsheet1 and script of spreadsheet1 sent request to spreadsheet2. Script of spreadsheet2 have doGet() function and do something. But nothing work.

I make two simple spreadsheets for exp.
[spreadsheet1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bbi9HDqBrbvp6SZJ2RRayDhU71oJyXV3UzSDuS9WjEk/edit?usp=sharing)
[spreadsheet2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XVu3jb9K7jdWf7nl2LbUfwrOuQEET0psGxjW_b-NYuE/edit?usp=sharing)

My code in spreadsheet1:

```
function myFunction() {

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script.google.com/d/15x62kDTppUbyUBo7LWKHG-Csw4yOKvxpodSYpYXoRGxky68O7Bx9uigZ");

Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

In **UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)** i use url of **spreadsheet2 script**.

My code in spreadsheet2:

```
function doGet(e) {

  Logger.log("GET запрос");

}

function doPost(e){

  Logger.log("POST запрос");      
}
```

> I read
>
> [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742350/google-apps-script-make-http-post) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38857531/how-to-make-post-requests-to-google-spreadsheets-using-javascript) [link3](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) [link4](https://ctrlq.org/code/19871-get-post-requests-google-script)
>
> but this does not work

Comment: When you say nothing works, do you mean you don't see your `Logger.log`  texts?

Comment: @ZektorH yes. I try to see does it work or not. So Function do nothing.

Comment: @contributorpw can you help me with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using the `Logger.log` function expecting to create a HTML response.

Try using the [TextOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/text-output) or the [HtmlOutput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output.html) objects to create your text instead.

Something like:

```
function doGet(e) {
   return ContentService.createTextOutput("GET запрос");
}

function doPost(e){
   return ContentService.createTextOutput("POST запрос");      
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: As i understand i need to deploy as a WebApp the google script to send get request to him. But can i sent get request to simple google script in google spreadsheet container ?

Comment: i will grateful to you if you will help :)

Comment: i read about  [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch#methods_1) where wrote ```fetch(url), HTTPResponse   - Makes a request to fetch a URL.``` - but it does not work (

Comment: Hello @DmitriyLavrov, what happens after you do the fetch?

Comment: Hello @ ZektorH. this is my [script](https://script.google.com/d/MUUhTFZMl3DUYrYG_5jhwgJOmxho0XLdw/edit?mid=ACjPJvH9vRAnJM64cIVHbbes56OLvJA286B_y6LdbidottIhRVg3wqE5JYEDk6HiOFX8yn10MJ3Zz9YfP0rnOYJXrD6p-1GM6W9IIrE2oXvP2MwbtxPWbCL5IcJn4vWRR9aCyNVGTVWJWTY&uiv=2). It is Spreadsheet1. So code is short ```function fun1() {
  Logger.log(" start");
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("URL_WebApp");
}```

Comment: Happens nothing. Script dont say about fails.

Comment: I think you should read more on the topic. Try following the [script examples](https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/parsing-html) and remember that `Logger.log` does not show text on the sheet, it just shows on the [Stackdriver Logs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging)

Comment: i know it. But i dont need to output html content. I just need to call doGet() in script2 from function script1. I can call doGet() in script2 by using copy url WebApp to browser. But i cant call it from script1 by using UrlFetchApp.fetch()

Comment: something similar there are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25228684/google-app-script-make-get-request-to-another-script-with-parameters/58285970#58285970) , but there are not full code to understend it.

Comment: `UrlFetchApp.fetch(addressOfYourSpreadsheet2WebApp);` is all you need to execute a doGet(e) on spreadsheet 2.

Comment: yes and i do the same. my code of script1 ```function fun1() {
  UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxaMxSYqgJB_bEHLuLEWEyOULna-VblHrTM7DiMmaLmbTEZ6OU/exec");
}

``` and no result. But if i copy url and past it to browser - its work.

Comment: i solve the problem. The problem was in access right.

Comment: In script2 i change the settings -  I opened access to all anonymous users from the Internet. Then calling the doget() function of script2 from script1 works.

Comment: Maybe i can turn on authorization, but i dont know how.